# Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model using nugetpackages

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp, nuget-package

I have been trying to create and run a simple program using the stanford-corenlp-3.5.2 nugetpackage.

However after looking up some beginner code to start I have found the following code props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");(Link to code example : http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html)

But whenever the console app loads pos it fires off a runtime error stating that it could not load a tagger.

I am wondering if i am missing any nugetpackages or if there is additional setup I have to go through. (Note. any time i have tried to add say the postagger nuget package i then get an error saying that the class Annotation is referenced in two dlls.)

I have found that if i remove some of the properties the application will run correctly so the new line looks like this
"props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");

Any help to get past the runtime error so I can continue further analyse of the sample text would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Attached picture for reference.(apparently I need more reputation in order to post a pic but when I can I will do so immediately :) Edit I have added the picture now :)

stack trace at line exception is as follows:

```
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories.4.create()
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(String name)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(Properties , Boolean , AnnotatorImplementations )
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props, Boolean enforceRequirements)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP..ctor(Properties props)
at ConApplicationSabrinaNLP.TestClass.donlp() in c:\Users\Justin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConApplicationSabrinaNLP\ConApplicationSabrinaNLP\TestClass.cs:line 28
at ConApplicationSabrinaNLP.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Justin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConApplicationSabrinaNLP\ConApplicationSabrinaNLP\Program.cs:line 20
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I don't know enough .NET to help fix the error, but the root cause is the missing corenlp models in the Java classpath. This is found in a *.jar file named `stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar`. The error manifests when the "pos" annotator tries to load its models from this jar.

Comment: I see. Since I have used nuget packages how would I add the missing .jar files? and or models to the nuget package? Or would I have to wait for whoever supports stanford-nlp to update its nuget package?

Comment: Looking at the C# code you linked, the culprit may be line 15: `var jarRoot = @"c:\models\stanford-corenlp-full-2015-01-30\stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models\";` -- This should point to the models jar

Comment: Ah yes, instead of loading the files manually to the project I added them using nuget in .net so everything(at least theoretically) is already referenced properly. I will try adding them manually to see if I get a different result. 

Also recently I posted a pic of my code hopefully that will help answer any futher questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't downloaded the models. The Nuget package doesn't work by itself. 
You must download lastest version here [POS-Tagger](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml)

Once you have done that put it in your project directory. Then point the code to it. In the "3.6.0  2015-12-09  Updated for compatibility" version the tagger has  a different name, "english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger" for example.
Make sure you point the code to the correct folder and files and it will work.

The following is a working example from my windows forms project.

```
using java.io;
using java.util;
using edu.stanford.nlp.ling;
using edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent;
using Console = System.Console;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stanford.NLP.POSTagger.CSharp
{
    class PosTagger

    {
        // get the base folder for the project
        public static string GetAppFolder()
        {
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath).Replace(@"*your project directory here*\bin\Debug", string.Empty);
        }

        public void testTagger()
        {
            var jarRoot = Path.Combine(GetAppFolder(), @"packages\stanford-postagger-2015-12-09");
            Console.WriteLine(jarRoot.ToString());
            var modelsDirectory = jarRoot + @"\models";

            // Loading POS Tagger
            var tagger = new MaxentTagger(modelsDirectory + @"\english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");

            // Text for tagging
            var text = "A Part-Of-Speech Tagger (POS Tagger) is a piece of software that reads text"
                       + "in some language and assigns parts of speech to each word (and other token),"
                       + " such as noun, verb, adjective, etc., although generally computational "
                       + "applications use more fine-grained POS tags like 'noun-plural'.";

            var sentences = MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(new java.io.StringReader(text)).toArray();
            foreach (ArrayList sentence in sentences)
            {
                var taggedSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
                Console.WriteLine(Sentence.listToString(taggedSentence, false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i try to run your code I get the following exception. "The type initializer for edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils threw an exception" when it hits the line  new MaxentTagger(...)

I have made sure the modelsDirectory is correct for my project.

Comment: Please give more details of the error. Get the details of the exception. It may be a dependency error.

Comment: My apologize for the delay. I got caught up with work. I will try my best to get back to you soon.

Comment: Again sorry for the delay just wanted to let you know that I havent forgotten and I will try to get back to you soon.

Comment: I've gotten this work in two projects. It really is just a case of installing it on nuget then downloading the latest package from the link provide. Store it in your project folder, where ever you can access it and fire away.